# Redirect Error Stream to File and Console in Windows

Tags: console, stream, pipe, stderr, redirectstandardoutput

I want to redirect error stream from java console application to file and console. In normal situation the error is displayed only in console. I want to be displayed in console and file. How can I achieve this? When I write:

```
java -classpath lib.jar com.hertz.test.Blad 2>error.log
```

Then the errors are redirecting to file but I don't see them on console. Also does anybody know how to add date and time to the logs in this situation?

I'm working in Windows 2003 Server.

Answer (score 3):

This is of course a simple exercise in piping the output through a filter, in this case the `tee` command, which is done in Microsoft's command interpreter much the same as in JP Software's TCC/LE and (non-C-shell family) Unix shells:

```
java -classpath lib.jar com.hertz.test.Blad 2>&1 | tee error-and-output.log
```

Treating standard output and standard error differently is little more than an exercise in redirection syntax, for which this example here is but one of several possibilities, and is a separate question.

```
java -classpath lib.jar com.hertz.test.Blad 2>&1 1>con | tee error.log
```

All that remains is to obtain a `tee` command.  There are several possibilities:

- **Use a port of a Unix `tee` command.** There are several choices.  Oft-mentioned are [GNUWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net./), [cygwin](http://cygwin.com./), and [unxutils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net./).  Less well known, but in some ways better, are the tools in the [SFUA utility toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=93FF2201-325E-487F-A398-EFDE5758C47F), which run in the [Subsystem for UNIX-based Applications](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc772343.aspx) that comes right there in the box with Windows 7 Ultimate edition and Windows Server 2008 R2.  (For Windows XP and Windows Server 2003, one can [download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=896c9688-601b-44f1-81a4-02878ff11778) and install [Services for UNIX version 3.5](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb496506.aspx).)  This toolkit has a large number of command-line TUI tools, from `mv` and `du`, through the Korn and C shells, to `perl` and `awk`.  It comes in both x86-64 and IA64 flavours as well as x86-32.  The programs run in Windows' native proper POSIX environment, rather than with emulator DLLs (such as `cygwin1.dll`) layering things over Win32.  And yes, the toolkit has `tee`, as well as some 300 others.
- **Use one of the many native Win32 `tee` commands that people have written and published.**  One such is [Ritchie Lawrence's `MTEE`](http://commandline.co.uk./mtee/), which as you can see has `/D` and `/T` options to add time and date stamps to each line that it processes.
- **Use a replacement command interpreter that comes with a built-in `TEE` command.** [JP Software's TCC/LE](http://jpsoft.com./tcmdledes.htm) is one such.  TCC/LE has [a built in `TEE` command](http://jpsoft.com./help/tee.htm).  As you can see, it also has `/D` and `/T` options to add time and date stamps to each line that it processes.

As an aside:  It's better for your application to add date and time stamps itself than for them to be post-processed by the `TEE` command.  For several reasons, relating both to how applications behave when their standard streams are pipes and to how pipes work, each line of output will not necessarily be processed by `TEE` at the time that your application generated it in the first place.  The leeway will affect both the relative (to one another) and the absolute (to the wall clock) accuracy of the timestamps that you see.